# Memcached on CentOS 6.6

Tags: php, laravel-4, memcached, centos6.5

I'm trying to get memcached to work on my CentOS 6.6 server in Laravel (PHP). It looks like I installed memcached correctly because when I type in "ps aux | grep memcached", I get a response showing it's running.

When I run phpinfo, I get the following:
[image]

I even have a little script that works via the command line when I type in "php test.php", but it doesn't work when I try to access it from the browser. Here is the script:

```
<?php
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("blah");

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No matching key found.  I'll add that now!";
    $mem->set("blah", "I am data!  I am held in memcached!") or die("Couldn't save anything to memcached...");
}
?>
```

So this script successfully caches when run from the command line, but doesn't cache when I run it from the browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: While this is programming related, you may get better responses on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why memcached only works from the command line, but I decided to try [Redis](http://redis.io/) instead. After installing, everything works without a hitch.